# loop through file saving to variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd, string-concatenation

I now have the following bat file working (which allows one to add text to the end of each line of a file)  -- please see also:
 [bat file: Use of if, for and a variable all together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978156/bat-file-use-of-if-for-and-a-variable-all-together)

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST "%FileToModify1%"  (
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%FileToModify1%) do (
    echo %%a   Note:  certain conditions apply  >> "%SaveFile1%"
  ) 
)
```

However, I  would like to save each line to a variable (including the new line symbol(s)) and then echo the variable to a file at the end.  Since there are several lines in the file it is really inefficient to save to a file with each line.

I tried googling this, but the answers do not fit my situation...

essentially I need the syntax for concatenating and saving to a variable (cumulatively like "+=" in C#), and also using the new lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you do not need to put everything into a variable, you just need to place the redirection at another position.
Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist "%FileToModify1%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%FileToModify1%") do (
        echo %%a   Note:  certain conditions apply
    )
) > "%SaveFile1%"

endlocal
```

Note that empty lines in the original file are ignored by `for /F`, so they are not transferred to the new file. Also lines starting with `;` are ignored by `for /F` (unless you change the `eol` option -- see `for /?`).

I modified the `for /F` options:

- no `delims` are allowed, so the each line is output as is (with `"tokens=* delims= "`, leading spaces are removed from each line if present);
- `usebackq` allows to surround the file specification in `""` which is helpful if it contains spaces;

---

#### Appendix A

If you still want to store the file content into a variable, you can do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem the two empty lines after the following command are mandatory:
set LF=^


if exist "%FileToModify1%" (
    set "FileContent="
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%FileToModify1%") do (
        set "FileContent=!FileContent!%%a   Note:  certain conditions apply!LF!"
    )
    (echo !FileContent!) > "%SaveFile1%"
)

endlocal
```

The file content is stored in variable `FileContent`, including the appendix `Note:  certain conditions apply`. `LF` holds the new-line symbol.

**Note:**
The length of a variable is very limited (as far as I know, 8191 bytes since Windows XP and 2047 bytes earlier)!

*[References:

[Store file output into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584412/5047996) (last code fragment);

[Explain how dos-batch newline variable hack works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379861/5047996)]*

---

#### Appendix B

Alternatively, you could store the file content in a array, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist "%FileToModify1%" (
    set /A cnt=0
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%FileToModify1%") do (
        set /A cnt+=1
        set "Line[!cnt!]=%%a   Note:  certain conditions apply"
    )

    (for /L %%i in (1,1,!cnt!) do (
        echo !Line[%%i]!
    )) > "%SaveFile1%"
)

endlocal
```

Each line of the file is stored in an array `Line[1]`, `Line[2]`, `Line[3]`, etc., including the appendix `Note:  certain conditions apply`. `cnt` contains the total number of lines, which is the array size.

**Note:**
Actually this is not a true array data type as such does not exist in batch, it is a collection of scalar variables with an array-style naming (`Line[1]`, `Line[2]`,...); therefore one might call it pseudo-array.

*[References:

[Store file output into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584412/5047996) (first code fragment);

[How to create an array from txt file within a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449767/5047996)]*

Comment: while this answer is nice, accepted, and probably better than saving to a variable, if anyone know how to do that it may help others who come here.....

Comment: I edited my answer and added my former (deleted) comments as Appendices including code snippets and references; I hope it is useful...

Answer (score 1):

you can write the output file in one shot:

```
(
  for /l %%i in (0,1,10) do (
   echo line %%i
  )
)>outfile.txt
```

(much quicker than appending each line separately)